# Apply Numpy to "for loops"

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, boxing

```
import numpy as np

c=[10,2000] # only two index for example 

horizontal=[]
vertical=[]

for i in range(0,c[0]):
    for j in range(0, c[1]):
        horizontal.append(j)
        vertical.append(i)

print horizontal
```

When I am working with arrays and for loops it is taking too much time. As I understand it it is wasting time because of undefined data type ("i" and "j"). I want to define the data type using NumPy and speed up the array loops.

How can I use NumPy for these "array for loops" or is there any other solution to speed up these loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do that with NumPy is [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) which creates a meshgrid:

```
vertical, horizontal = np.mgrid[0:c[0], 0:c[1]]
vertical = vertical.ravel()       # make it 1D
horizontal = horizontal.ravel()   # make it 1D
```

Comment: You were fast this time! ;)